# Jerky javascript animation in Firefox when moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm a physicist and I started learning JS for fun. I'm trying to write an animation of a pendulum. When I run it in Firefox, it gets really jerky when I merely move the mouse, but when I run it in Edge or Chrome the problem doesn't occur. Apart from knowing a bit of C++ I'm a noob! I've tried to read up online, but couldn't find the answer. I've added a minimal example below. Why does it happen and how can I stop that?

I've actually also added a function (not included in the example below) which calculates the time elapsed between subsequent repetitions of the main loop, and based on that, displays the number of dropped frames. When I was running the program for 10-20s and I was constantly moving the mouse, in Edge or Chrome there were just 5-6 dropped frames. In Firefox there were way over 100 of them

*Edit 04.03.2021*: Here is the code with the fps counter. The last line is meant to show the number of dropped frames: 1, 2, 3, 4 or more in a row. I've also checked the program on another computer on Firefox (version 75.0 if it matters) - no frame drops! And on this computer I've clean reinstalled Firefox (86.0) - and there are still these drops when I move the mouse.

Here I ran the performance check. At around 4500ms I started moving the mouse. I don't understand much of it but I can tell the requestAnimationFrame wasn't even called in every frame.
[image]

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var color_obj = '#00AA00'

var pivot_x = window.innerWidth/2 , pivot_y = window.innerHeight/2;
var pivot_wx = window.innerHeight/25 , pivot_wy = pivot_wx;    
var pivot_ax = 0 , pivot_ay = 0;
var pivot_vx1 = 0 , pivot_vy1 = 0 , pivot_vx2 = 0 , pivot_vy2 = 0;

var ball_l = window.innerHeight/3;
var ball_ang = Math.PI/3;
var ball_sin , ball_cos;
var ball_x = pivot_x + ball_l * Math.sin(ball_ang);
var ball_y = pivot_y + ball_l * Math.cos(ball_ang);
var ball_r = window.innerHeight/25;

var ball_eps = 0;
var ball_om = 0;

var g = 10 * window.innerHeight/50;
var dt = 0.1;

var timer = new o_timer();

var i;

ctx.font = 20 +'px Arial';
                                                    
main();

// --------------------------------------------------- MAIN LOOP

function main ()
{   
    f_calculate();

    f_clearscreen();

    timer.tick();
    timer.display(0.7*window.innerWidth,10);

    f_draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

//-------------------------------------------- PHYSICS


function f_calculate()    
{       
    ball_sin = (ball_x - pivot_x) / ball_l;
    ball_cos = (ball_y - pivot_y) / ball_l;
    
    ball_eps = ( - g * ball_sin - pivot_ax * ball_cos + pivot_ay * ball_sin ) / ball_l;
    ball_om = ball_om + ball_eps * dt;
    ball_ang = ball_ang + ball_om * dt;
    
    if(ball_ang > Math.PI) ball_ang = ball_ang - 2*Math.PI;
    else if(ball_ang < -Math.PI) ball_ang = ball_ang + 2*Math.PI;

    ball_x = pivot_x + ball_l * Math.sin(ball_ang);
    ball_y = pivot_y + ball_l * Math.cos(ball_ang);

}

// ---------------------------------------------- DRAWING

function f_clearscreen()                                            
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function f_draw ()
{
                                        // Draws string

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( pivot_x , pivot_y );
    ctx.lineTo( ball_x , ball_y );
    ctx.stroke();

                                        // Draws pivot

    ctx.fillStyle = color_obj;
    ctx.fillRect(pivot_x - pivot_wx/2, pivot_y - pivot_wy/2 , pivot_wx , pivot_wy);
    ctx.strokeRect(pivot_x - pivot_wx/2, pivot_y - pivot_wy/2 , pivot_wx , pivot_wy);

                                        // Draws ball
    
    ctx.fillStyle = color_obj;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball_x, ball_y, ball_r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

// --------------------------------------------------------

function o_timer()
{   
    this.t_old = 0;
    this.t_new = 0;

    this.duration = 0;
    this.duration_frames = 0;           

    this.dt = 0;

    this.fps = 0;
    this.fps_displayT = 500;
    this.fps_counter_old = 0;
    this.fps_counter_new = 0;
    this.fps_tick_number = 0;

    this.fps_drop_count = [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ];    

    this.tick = function()
    {
                    // calculates duration between subsequent ticks
        this.t_old = this.t_new;
        this.t_new = performance.now();
        this.duration = this.t_new - this.t_old;
    
                            // provides realistic dt for physics
        this.dt = this.duration / 1000;
    
                    // calculates tick number per every fps display 
        this.fps_tick_number = this.fps_tick_number + 1;
        this.fps_counter_old = this.fps_counter_new;
        this.fps_counter_new = this.t_new % this.fps_displayT;
        if(this.fps_counter_old > this.fps_counter_new)
        {
            this.fps = 1000 * this.fps_tick_number / this.fps_displayT;
            this.fps_tick_number = 0;
        }
            // calculates the duration in frames (assuming 60 Hz)
                                                            
        this.duration_frames = Math.round( 60 * this.duration / 1000 );
    
                    // counts dropped frames (1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , more)
        if( this.duration_frames >= 2 && this.duration_frames <= 5 )
        {
            this.fps_drop_count[ this.duration_frames - 2 ] += 1;
        }
        else if ( this.duration_frames > 5 )
        {
            this.fps_drop_count[4] += 1;
        }
    }   
                                    // for displaying fps etc.
    this.line_height = 25;

    this.display = function(_x , _y )
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#00AA00';  
        ctx.fillText(this.duration + ' ms', _x , _y + this.line_height); 
        ctx.fillText(this.fps + ' fps',  _x , _y + 2*this.line_height );    
        ctx.fillText(this.fps_drop_count ,  _x , _y + 3*this.line_height ); 
    }
}
```

```css
html { 
  -ms-touch-action: none; /* Direct all pointer events to JavaScript code. */
}
canvas {
  background: white;
  display: block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong in here. Is your fps meter really all that is not here on this question? Could you add it too? Otherwise, could you remove anyhing else on your side to be sure it's this the cause? Also be sure to deactivate any extension on your browser. And finally use the "performance" tab of your browser to check what causes the dropped frames.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. It seems smooth to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've editted the post to include what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of an update for anyone who might be reading this in the future.

The reason for the frame drops was not in the code. In fact I was getting the same frame drops when I removed the pendulum and left only the empty canvas with the fps counter.

The reason was I was running this on Surface Pro on battery. When Surface was plugged in to the power supply, there were no frame drops. I also checked different browsers with Surface on battery, and I was getting less frame drops on Chrome. So the reason must have been some power saving options on my computer and also some kind of a limited efficiency of the browser.

The question remains what I could do to minimize this. Maybe create smaller canvas, draw on it and then scale it up? Or somehow update the screen only in areas where things are changing? I haven't tried it yet. But that's a topic for another thread.